# Is there any way to make mesh round?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model skirt, and I finished most of the mesh.
I want to make mesh round to make it skirt shape, but I can't find any way. I tried to use curve and simple deform modifier, but not working. Is there any way?
[image]

Comment: Both methods should work, maybe you've done it wrong, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: uploaded https://pasteall.org/blend/34369236ef53461ca447660666ef4999

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply the rotation and scale of the object and choose a *Bend* on Z at 360°:

[image]

Also you can add a *Lattice* modifier in order to give your skirt the profile.